# Search a pattern between two patterns and then add a line above or below that pattern using sed command

Tags: sed

Let there be a file like..

```
Mango
Apple
Orange
Lenovo
Cherry
Stack
Stack
```

Now i want to search for *cherry* between the lines containing *apple* and *stack* and the insert a new line above *cherry*

Output should look like

```
Mango
Apple
Orange
Lenovo
**NEWLINE**
Cherry
Stack
Stack
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed '/Apple/,/Stack/{s/Cherry/**Newline**\n&/}' file
```

#### explanation

- `/Apple/,/Stack/` search the pattern between `Apple` and `Stack`
- `s/Cherry/**Newline**\n&/` replace command `s`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/apple/I,/stack/I!b;/cherry/Ii\\' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/Apple/,/Stack/ {if ($0~/Cherry/) $0="**NEWLINE**"RS$0}8'
Mango
Apple
Orange
Lenovo
**NEWLINE**
Cherry
Stack
Stack
```

This search from `Apple` to `Stack` and if line with `Cherry` found, insert new line above.